# How to change font size of plot title when the title is a variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to generate a scatter plot. I made the title into a variable, how can I change the font size? The code is as the following:

```
library("ggplot2")
plotfunc <- function(x){
    x +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "lm",  color = "blue", size = 1) +
    opts(title = plottitle,
           axis.title.x = theme_text(size = 8, colour = 'black'),
         axis.title.y = theme_text(size = 8, colour = 'black', angle = 90))
}

plottitle <- "This is Title"
p <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))
plotfunc(p)
```

I tried

```
opts(title = plottitle (size = 10),...
```

but there was an error:

```
Error in opts(title = plottitle(size = 10),
axis.title.x = theme_text(size = 8,  : could not find function "plottitle"
```

It was recognized as function which was not what I want.
What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: I tried running your example, but I don't have the 'label' function you use, also you should consider adding an `require(ggplot2)`. If your example is actually reproducible it's much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 8):

If **opts()** still works for you then you are using an old version of ggplot2. The newer command is **theme()**. In any case you don't want to put the actual title label into **opts** or **theme** -- use **labs()**

```
plotfunc <- function(x) {
  x +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "lm",  color = "blue", size = 1) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8, colour = 'black'),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8, colour = 'black', angle = 90)) +
    labs(title='this', x='that', y='the other')
}

## plottitle <- "This is Title"
p <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))
plotfunc(p)
```

[image]

Comment: FYI -- if you pass `theme()` stuff before `theme_bw()` as you do above, your `size = 8` options will have no effect. `theme_bw()` is a preset that will overwrite `theme()` settings (added a note about this in my answer below). Try changing to `size = 2` and you'll note nothing changes.  Putting `theme_bw() +` before `theme(...)` will work; it will first apply the preset, and then `theme(...)` arguments will overwrite `theme_bw()`'s settings where applicable.

Answer (score 6):

Ridiculously late answer, but I didn't think the existing answers addressed the actual question:

> I made the title into a variable, how can I change the font size?

This works for me and is in the updated `ggplot` syntax (`theme()` vs. `opts()`):

```
library(ggplot2)
plotfunc <- function(x){
    x +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "lm",  color = "blue", size = 1) +
    labs(title = plottitle) +
    ### pay attention to the ordering of theme_bw() vs. theme()
    theme_bw() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12),
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8))

}

plottitle <- "This is Title"
p <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))
plotfunc(p)
```

I get the following:

[image: ggplot theme(plot.title)]

A note about my `theme_bw()` comment: try running the above, but put `theme_bw()` last, after the `theme(plot.title, ...)` bit, as in Stephen Henderson's answer above. You'll note that none of the font sizes take effect. This is because `theme_bw()` is a preset which will overwrite various custom `theme()` options if you pass it after they are added.

Just a finnicky thing to watch out for; I've only learned it due to using `theme_bw()` a lot and banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why other `theme()` options weren't working before realizing it wasn't my `ggplot` syntax after all, but the order of my settings. Gotta love coding :)

Also, here's [the full list of options](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) you can pass to `theme()` as a reference for what you can tweak and how.

Answer (score 1):

You put a "(" as the next non-whitespace character after `plottitle` so the interpreter decided it must be a function. Try

```
  .... opts( title=plottile, size=10)
```

This was the long list of warming messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: 'opts' is deprecated.
Use 'theme' instead.
See help("Deprecated") 
2: 'theme_text' is deprecated.
Use 'element_text' instead.
See help("Deprecated") 
3: 'theme_text' is deprecated.
Use 'element_text' instead.
See help("Deprecated") 
4: In opts(title = plottitle, axis.title.x = theme_text(size = 8, colour = "black"),  :
  Setting the plot title with opts(title="...") is deprecated. Use labs(title="...") or ggtitle("...") instead.
```

Comment: I tried `opts( title = plottitle,size = 10) + opts(axis.title.x = theme_text(size = 8, colour = 'black'),axis.title.y = theme_text(size = 8, colour = 'black', angle = 90))` There was an error: `Error:"size" is not a valid theme element name`

Comment: Yet another error and not one that was foreseeable from your code. Furthermore when I run the code I only get warnings about deprecated use of opts, but I do get that title on the plot.