# How to increase the font size of ggtitle in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to increase the font size of ggtitle and also the font should be bold. My code is as follows.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x1, y = value, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_point(size=2) + 
  ggtitle("male vs.female") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold")) + 
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12)) + 
  labs(x = "x axis", y = "y axis") + 
  ylim(0,100) + xlim(0,100) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "blue"), 
                      labels = c("male", "female"))
```

Comment: maybe this could help you http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Fonts/

Comment: Giving us a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5965451/2641825) would be great.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use [theme()](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html), here is an example  :

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed,y=dist)) + 
    ggtitle("cars") + geom_point() + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 40, face = "bold"))
```

[image]

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806526/2641825).

Comment: stating the obvious here, but took me 10 minutes to figure it out, if you're using a ``theme`` that sets a ``plot.title`` size, make sure to insert the ``theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 40, face = "bold"))`` line __after__ your call to ``theme_blabla()``, otherwise your theme's plot title size will override it.

Comment: Also you must set `plot.title` **not** `title`.