# Changing the size of the subtitle of ggtitle

Tags: r, ggplot2

My question is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458230/how-to-increase-the-font-size-of-ggtitle-in-ggplot2). But I cannot figure out how it works for the subtitle and when you already have another theme in there as well.

I have data as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

df_a <- structure(list(`Sample Selection` = c("Answers Private", "Answers Private", 
"Answers Public", "Answers Public", "All Participants", "All Participants"
), category = c("A. % mean tax compliance", "B. % mean corporate compliance", 
"A. % mean tax compliance", "B. % mean corporate compliance", 
"A. % mean tax compliance", "B. % mean corporate compliance"), 
    total = c(660, 550, 582, 485, 1242, 1035), percentage = c(40.4545454545455, 
    44.9090909090909, 45.7044673539519, 54.8453608247423, 42.914653784219, 
    49.5652173913043), count = c(267, 247, 266, 266, 533, 513
    ), p_value = c(0.0621323326097826, 0.0014205180679509, 0.0621323326097826, 
    0.0014205180679509, 0.00151992181366903, 0.00151992181366903
    ), stars = structure(c(".", "**", ".", "**", "**", "**"), legend = "0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1", class = "noquote")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
    
   Sample Selection                       category total percentage count p_value stars
1:  Answers Private       A. % mean tax compliance   660         40   267  0.0621     .
2:  Answers Private B. % mean corporate compliance   550         45   247  0.0014    **
3:   Answers Public       A. % mean tax compliance   582         46   266  0.0621     .
4:   Answers Public B. % mean corporate compliance   485         55   266  0.0014    **
5: All Participants       A. % mean tax compliance  1242         43   533  0.0015    **
6: All Participants B. % mean corporate compliance  1035         50   513  0.0015    **



df_a %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = category, y = percentage, fill = `Sample Selection`, label=sprintf("%.01f %%", round(percentage, digits = 2)))) + 
    geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
    geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
              vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
              size = 4) +           
    scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.5) +
    theme_bw(base_size = 15) + 
    geom_signif(annotation=c("p=0.002"), y_position = c(70), xmin=c(0.7),
              xmax=c(1.7)) + ## between ESCOT levels +
    geom_signif(annotation=c("p=0.06", "p=0.001"), y_position = c(60, 60), xmin=c(1,2),
              xmax=c(1.25,2.25)) + ## Within ESCOT levels but between groups
    xlab("p-values from test of proportions") +
    ylab("Percentage Compliant/Honest") +
    ggtitle("Figure X.", subtitle = "p-values from test of proportions") + 
    scale_shape_manual(values = c('p_value' = 17), name = 'stars')
```

How would I change the font size of the subtitle in this case?

Comment: Try with `+ theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 40))`

Comment: Thank you very much! Now that I see it I feel like maybe I should have been able to figure that out myself. But these `theme` things always confuse me a bit.